# Vim : How to start and stop logging everything going on?

Tags: debugging, vim

How can I log everything going on in vim between two moments ?

For some context, when I type characters, my cursor goes to the end of the line and go back at its expected position, like a glitch. I would then like to know what is causing this behaviour. (But I had other situation in the past such a feature would have helped me a lot)

Thus, is there a way to log everything going on (user inputs, auto commands executed etc.) between two moments ? (something like : "start recording in file.log" and "stop recording")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can log actions in Vim if you set verbose level in opened editor:

```
:set verbose=15
```

where 15 is debug level (it can be any number between 1 and 15, where 15 is the most detailed logging). If you want to save debug output into a file, you can execute:

```
:set verbosefile=log.txt
```

Check the [full article](http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/10/31/debugging-vim/) by Jonathan Lehman where he explains it